# TRINO minute sequence creation

Tags: sql, presto, date-arithmetic, trino

I am trying to create a sequence in minutes between current_date - 4 months (00:00:00.000000 time) and current_date - 1 day (00:00:00.000000 time) (see screenshot).  I am using the below query and gives correct start time and day, but the the stop time is 00:59:00.000 instead of 00:00:00.000000 (day is correct).
Any help what I am missing?

```
SELECT 
        current_date as current_date_,
        current_date - INTERVAL '4' MONTH AS date_one,
        current_date - INTERVAL '1' DAY AS date_two,
        DATE_ADD('MINUTE', m, h) AS dates_m
FROM UNNEST(SEQUENCE(current_date - INTERVAL '4' MONTH, DATE_TRUNC('DAY', LOCALTIMESTAMP) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, INTERVAL '1' HOUR)) AS t(h)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SEQUENCE(0, 59)) AS t(m)
    ORDER BY dates_m
```

[image]
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cross-joining two sequences, why not generate all intermediate timestamps at once?

Unfortunately I can't test this since I don't have a Presto database at hand, but based on [the documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#sequence) (emphasis added):

> **sequence(start, stop, step)**
>
> Generate a sequence of timestamps **from `start` to `stop`**, incrementing by `step`. The type of step can be either `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` or `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH`.

Doesn't this just work?

```
select date_m
from unnest(
    sequence(
        current_date - interval '4' month,
        current_date,
        interval '1' minute
    )
) t(date_m)
```

Not sure whether Presto figures out that, since we are giving an interval in minutes, we want a *timestamp* sequence altough both boundaries are *dates*. If not, you might need to cast the boundaries to `timestamp`s:

```
select date_m
from unnest(
    sequence(
        cast(current_date as timestamp) - interval '4' month,
        cast(current_date as timestamp),
        interval '1' minute
    )
) t(date_m)
```

Comment: This code gives me an error: TrinoUserError(type=USER_ERROR, name=INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT, message="sequence step must be a day interval if start and end values are dates", query_id=20221104_091129_76471_kqra8)

Comment: @Robbie: cf the last part of my answer… Presto probably wants `cast(current_date as timestamp)` instead of `current_date` in the boundaries.

Comment: I added a WHERE in my code that was removing the part I did not want. Solved. Thanks